# How to add permanent data to GridView in C#

Tags: c#

When I add data to a `GridView` how do i make the data stay there permanently until I remove it, so even when I open and close the form the data doesn't get deleted. I'm using it as a database for a login system.

This is the code I have so far but it only adds items to the `GridView`.

```
private void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   dataGridView1.Rows.Add(Usertxt.Text, Passtxt.Text, PrivelegeCB.Text, 1);           
}
```

If there are better ways to make a database for users that doesn't use sql feel free to put it in

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name!

Comment: Don't store data in a datagridwhatever, store it in a datatable

Comment: You can't permanently store data in a datagridview because when you close the form the datagridview ceases to exist. You have to save the data before it closes and reload the data when it next opens. If you're using a database this is what the database is for. If you're not using a database it would be easiest to put the data in a datatable and save/load it to/from xml (datatable has methods that do that)

Comment: As stated, store the data in a DataTable bound to your DataGridView. You can then save it to your data or save the DataTable to a XML file that you can load when the window opens.